# Why colorbar cannot work with heatmap fuse to scatter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I work with two graphics, and they are fuse. It's a heatmap fuse to a scatter but the heatmap doesn't have colorbar and I want to show this color. When I try to do it it give me an error:

`RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).`

Here's the code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("data/forestfires.csv")

x_number_list = df.X.tolist()
y_number_list = df.Y.tolist()
x_number_list = np.array(x_number_list)
y_number_list = np.array(y_number_list)

area_number_list = df.area.tolist()
area_number_list = [int(round(x+1,0)) for x in area_number_list]
temperature_number_list = df.temp.tolist()
temperature_number_list = np.array(temperature_number_list)

heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(y_number_list, x_number_list, weights=temperature_number_list)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
ax1.imshow(heatmap, interpolation='bicubic', cmap='hot', origin='lower')
ax1.scatter(x_number_list, y_number_list, s=area_number_list, color=(157/255, 173/255, 245/255, 0.9))
ax1.set_ylim(y_number_list.min()-0.5, y_number_list.max()+0.5)
ax1.set_xlim(x_number_list.min()-0.5, x_number_list.max()+0.5)

cb = plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

here's the result of the plot:

[image]

All data I use in this program are number. I work on jupyter and I use the lastest version on python.

Comment: Depending on whether you want a colorbar for the image or the scatter you need to pass the return of either function as input to the `colorbar(mappable)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify where you want to have to colorbar and what you want the colorbar to show. I would do it in the following fashion.

Change

```
ax1.imshow(heatmap, interpolation='bicubic', cmap='hot', origin='lower')
```

to

```
im = ax1.imshow(heatmap, interpolation='bicubic', cmap='hot', origin='lower')
```

and then specify the colorbar as

```
cb = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax1)
```

Comment: It show a colorbar but the color bar doesn't have the good parameter, I explain: the value of my heatmap go from 0 to 1000 and  my colorbar have these values in max and min paramater. But in fact I want a colorbar with the with the values of the weights list (temparature_number list). Is it possible or not ?

Comment: I try to use clim like this `im.set_clim(temperature_number_list.min(), temperature_number_list.max())` but it change the heatmap color. I want to keep the heatmap as it is and change the colorbar extremum

Comment: It makes sense that the heatmap changes when you change the colorbar. It is supposed to change the heatmap when changing the extrema of the colorbar. Otherwise the colors would not give the right representation.